# Spring @Cacheable doesn't cache public methods

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have following method;

```
    @Cacheable(value = "psgSiteToMap", key = "'P2M_'.concat(#siteName)")
    public Map getSiteDetail(String siteName) {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        .....
        //construct map variable here
        .......
        return map;
    }
```

While project startup, cannot autowire class this method belongs to. If i change above method as following;

```
    @Cacheable(value = "psgSiteToMap", key = "'P2M_'.concat(#siteName)")
    private Map getSiteDetail(String siteName) {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        .....
        //construct map variable here
        ................
        return map;
    }

    public Map getSiteDetailPublic(String siteName) {
         return this.getSiteDetail(siteName);
    }
```

it works. Is there any restriction on `@Cacheable` annotation for public methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used it in my project for public methods, it just works fine. Also the Ehcache [documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/spring#cacheable) doesn't say anything of that sort. The example shown in the link uses a public method.

Comment: @ShashankKadne In other class, i also use for public methods and it works fine. However, in this class it doesn't work for method getSiteDetail(String siteName)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spring AOP works only on public methods by default.** You'd need AspectJ and load time or compile time weaving to make it work on private methods.

So it *works* in your case means that when you move the `@Cacheable` to the `private` method the proxy is not created at all and that *works* is autowireing, but not caching.

You probably have not set `proxy-target-class` property in your XML configuration or its equivalent annotation attribute. Can you please add the Spring configuration you're using and the class definition line. I'm interested if it implements any interfaces? Than I'll expand my answer with more details.